# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error PDColoredProgressView

Tags: xcode, xcode4, mach-o

I'm trying to use PDColoredProgressView [from here](https://github.com/PascalW/PDColoredProgressview). It was working, but for some reason, XCode decided it wasn't having it and throws up 27 Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Errors. Huh? Can anyone decode this? Thanks!

```
Ld /Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-cqamvgtgfzdealbjtkomtjzxkdgr/Build/Intermediates/xxxxxxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxxxx.build/Objects-normal/armv6/xxxxx normal armv6
    cd "/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/iPhone Apps/xxxxx"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -L/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-cqamvgtgfzdealbjtkomtjzxkdgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-cqamvgtgfzdealbjtkomtjzxkdgr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-cqamvgtgfzdealbjtkomtjzxkdgr/Build/Intermediates/xxxxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxxxx.build/Objects-normal/armv6/xxxxx.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -o /Users/xxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-cqamvgtgfzdealbjtkomtjzxkdgr/Build/Intermediates/xxxxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxxxx.build/Objects-normal/armv6/xxxxx

Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_CGRectGetMinX", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGRectGetMinY", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextIsPathEmpty", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextSaveGState", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGRectGetHeight", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextStrokeRect", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextRestoreGState", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGRectGetWidth", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextTranslateCTM", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextScaleCTM", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextSetRGBFillColor", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextMoveToPoint", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextFillRect", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextClip", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextAddLineToPoint", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextStrokePath", referenced from:
      -[PDColoredProgressView drawRect:] in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextAddRect", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGGradientRelease", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextDrawLinearGradient", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextAddArcToPoint", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents", referenced from:
      _fillRectWithLinearGradient in PDColoredProgressView.o
  "_CGContextClosePath", referenced from:
      _addRoundedRectToPath in PDColoredProgressView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thank you!

*Note: I removed my username and app name from the error message and replaced them with x's

Answer (score 0):

From Error log, I believe you are missing project or library Architecture settings (depending on where you used above code). Just add armv6(or its equivalent architecture name) in project settings and things should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the Core Graphics library installed! Add the core graphics library then in the PDColoredProgressView.h add `#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>`..

You may also need QuartzCore for some of the stuff you are doing! armv7 has nothing to do with it I dunno why they threw that in there haha!